# The listener attribute in <p:ajax> is not working JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to refresh the content of one of my components when I choose different options in my p:selectOneMenu but I've realized that the listener doesn't follow the change of state
This is my xhtml file

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">Configuration</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
                                        <h:form id="option_form">
                                            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
                                        <div class="p-field">
                                         <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{myBean.selectedOption}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mobile" itemValue="option1" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bancaire" itemValue="option2" />
                                            <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.handleRadioChange()}" event="change" update=":option_form:selectedOptionPanel"  process="@this" />
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                                        </div>
                                      <p:outputPanel id="selectedOptionPanel">
                                         <h:panelGroup id="option1" rendered="#{myBean.option1Selected}">
                                       <h5>Option 1</h5>
                                      </h:panelGroup>
                                       <h:panelGroup id="option2" rendered="#{myBean.option2Selected}">
                                       <h6>Ici c'est l'option 2</h6>
                                      </h:panelGroup>
                                      </p:outputPanel>     
                                      <p:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.save()}" value="Enregistrer"></p:commandButton>                      
                            </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And this is my bean

```
@Data
@Named
@SessionScoped
@Slf4j
public class MyBean {

    private String selectedOption;
     private boolean option1Selected;
     private boolean option2Selected;
     @Digits(integer = 10, message = "Veuillez entrez un montant valide", fraction = 0)
     public static  Double amount;
     private Double mont ;
    
@PostConstruct
     public void init( ) {
        selectedOption = "option1";
    }

    public String getSelectedOption() {
            return selectedOption;
        }
        
        public void setSelectedOption(String selectedOption) {
            this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
        }
        
        public boolean isOption1Selected() {
            return "option1".equals(selectedOption);
        }
        
        public void setOption1Selected(boolean option1Selected) {
            this.option1Selected = option1Selected;
        }
        
        public boolean isOption2Selected() {
            return "option2".equals(selectedOption);
        }
        
        public void setOption2Selected(boolean option2Selected) {
            this.option2Selected = option2Selected;
        }
     
        public void save() {
            log.info(selectedOption);
        }
        
        public void handleRadioChange() {
            log.info(selectedOption);
            System.out.println(selectedOption);
        /*  if (selectedOption != null) {
                option1Selected = selectedOption.equals("option1");
                option2Selected = selectedOption.equals("option2");      
            }*/
        }
}
```

I read many topics about this issue and I've experienced almost all of the solutions but nothing of them is working.